# Disprove using set identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A,B,C$ be sets. Draw a Venn diagram and color the region $(A-C)\cap(B- C)$.
>   disprove that $(A-C)\cap(B- C) = \emptyset$.

Already done the first part, but the proving part I am stuck at. 
I have no clue on how to do this. Please show/guide me

Comment: Take for example $A=B$, what happens then?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Prove **or disprove**.  Do you have reason to believe that $(A\setminus C)\cap (B\setminus C) = \emptyset$?  You suggest that you successfully completed the first step and colored on a venn diagram.  Did you *color anything* when coloring the region?  Or did you leave it blank?  Since you colored something, what does that imply about the truth of the statement?

Comment: Now... as for how to give a counterexample... you literally just pick some arbitrary numbers and sets to use such that the proposed identity is false... in other words so that $(A\setminus C)\cap (B\setminus C)$ is *not* empty.  The example doesn't need to be very complicated.  You should be able to assign simple sets such as $\emptyset,\{1\}$ and/or $\{1,2\}$ to $A,B,C$ in such a way to get it to work how you like.

Comment: Sorry, @JMoravitz. Wrote completely wrong. I meant  (A−C)∩(B−C)=∅  and not (A∖C)∩(B∖C)=∅.

Comment: Those mean the same thing.  Both $-$ and $\setminus$ are used as [set difference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html), the only difference being author preference or possibly context, but it is clear from context that set difference is what you are referring to.  $\setminus$ is seen as more "proper" since it can't be confused with $X-Y=\{x-y~:~x\in X,y\in Y\}$, hence the earlier edit.

Comment: What did you find with the Venn Diagram?  Did you find it was true or false?

Comment: Hi @fleablood, When i colored the Venn Diagram, I colored A and B and between them. But not C.

Comment: Good, so you did *color something*.  Now... what do you know of that venn diagrams are used to represent?  You can have [each circle represent something and have individual elements within each circle](http://myfuturepast.blogspot.com/2012/09/a-venn-diagram-my-next-car.html).  Now... just interpret $A$ as the set consisting of all elements within the first circle, $B$ as the set consisting of all elements within the second circle, etc...  If you don't want to be creative and use cars, you could have just used [region labels](http://cstl-cla.semo.edu/hhill/PL120/notes/venn%20validity.htm)

Comment: Or, better yet, you could do as was suggested earlier and use particularly small simple examples like $A=B=\{1\}$ and $C=\emptyset$

Comment: Now... "*I colored $A$ and $B$ and between them*"  That sounds to me like you colored regions I,II and IV in lulu's image below.  That is incorrect.  That would have been for $(A\setminus C)\color{red}{\cup}(B\setminus C)$ rather than $(A\setminus C)\color{red}{\cap}(B\setminus C)$.  You should have only colored region IV

Comment: "That sounds to me like you colored regions I,II and IV in lulu's image below. "  .......Ahem........  (actually I stole this image... not sure who from anymore but  I doubt it was lulu.....)

Comment: Yeah, I colored I,II and IV. Might have been wrong :/

Comment: But, if you colored *anything* you should have interpreted as *NOT* empty.

Comment: $I,II, IV$ would represent $(A - C)\cup(B-C)$  (or ($A\cup B)-C$).

Comment: @fleablood I see the problem now! So what I basically should have done was to just color IV.

Comment: @fleablood ?  Where did you come from?  [Lulu!  Where did you go?](https://youtu.be/MTLp14MKDDU?t=67)  Don't know how my mind works at times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Already done the first part"

And what'd you get?

I get:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Where $I$ and $IV$ make up $A-C$ and $II$ and $IV$ make up $B-C$ and $IV$ make up $(A-C) \cap (B-C)$ which need not be empty.

> "but the proving part I am stuck at"

Can't prove what isn't true.  So we need a counter example.  Any normal set will do.  But I already had those symbols in (for another reason) so I'll just use them.

Let $A = \{1,4,5,7\}$, Let $B=\{2,4,6,7\}$ and let $C = \{3,5,6,7\}$.

Then $A-C=\{1,4,5,7\}-\{3,5,6,7\} = \{1,4\}$ and $B-C=\{2,4,6,7\} -\{3,5,6,7\}=\{2,4\}$.

And $(A-C)\cap (B-C) = \{1,4\}\cap \{2,4\} = \{4\}$.

.....

Or if I wanted to be clever and as simple and blunt as possible.

Let $A=B=\{x\}$ and let $C=\emptyset$.  Then

$$\begin{align}
A-C&= A-\emptyset\\
&=A \\
&=B \\
&=\{x\}
\end{align}$$ and

$$\begin{align}
B-C&=B-\emptyset \\
&=B\\
&=A \\
&=\{x\}
\end{align}$$ and

$$\begin{align}
(A-C)\cap (B-C)&=A\cap B\\
& =A\cap A \\
&= A\\
&=B\\
&=\{x\}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can "cheat" for the first part by taking each of $A, B, C$ as distinct, nonintersecting and nonempty.

For the second part, consider $A=B$ to be nonempty with $C=\varnothing$.